# Create an Arc and a Pie using DIV DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a created an ellipse using `div` DOM element.

```
var body = document.querySelector('body');
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.style.borderRadius = '50%';
div.style.border = '1px solid red'; 
div.style.left = '60px'; 
div.style.top =  '60px';
div.style.width = '100px';
div.style.height = '100px'; 
body.appendChild(div);
```

It looks like the image below:

[image]

I want also to create an arc and a pie.

[image]

In the second image above, the user will just input the `starting angle` and the `end angle` of the arc. In our case, the starting angle is `180` degrees and the ending angle is `360` degrees.

I want also to create a pie, wherein the user must input the inside radius of the circle/ellipse, starting angle and ending angle.

[image]

In the third picture, the `inside radius` is `50%` of the width of the circle/ellipse, the starting angle is `90` degrees and the ending angle is `360` also.

Is it possible?

P.S: I don't want to draw it in the canvas or use svg.

Comment: you can draw this easily using canvas

Comment: here is pie https://jsfiddle.net/63wnb5gu/

Comment: @FastSnail --> But how can I specify my starting angle and ending angle?

Comment: this method is very limited you can only draw angles of 45degree multiples. for example you cannot draw 30 angle arc.i think you can do draw more angles using gradient style

Comment: sorry it's actually 90 s multiples you cannot draw 45 but 0 90 180 360.is it ok do you want user to draw outside of these angles?

Comment: i answered.you can see how to specify start-end angles

Comment: for second example logic is still same you should create 2 divs for circles 2 divs for close circles https://jsfiddle.net/63wnb5gu/1

Answer (score 1):

As i said canvas is very good solution to draw this kind of things.however since you don't want to use canvas you can use border styles to draw arcs but angle of arc should be `90deg` multiples like `0 90 180 270 360`.however start angle can be any angle 0,5,10,7...

here is an example.

to get the effect of 2nd arc you given, enter start angle as `0` and end angle as `180`. because stranded angle system is : see following picture

[image]

run this code

```js
var border = ['border-top-color', 'border-right-color', 'border-bottom-color', 'border-left-color'];
var circle;
var standeredRotation = 135;

function getinput() {
  circle = document.getElementById("circle");
  var startAngle = document.getElementById("startangle").value;
  var endAngle = document.getElementById("endtangle").value;
  var angle = endAngle - startAngle;
  if (angle % 90 != 0) {
    alert("plz enter 90's multiples");
  } else {
    var parts = angle / 90;
    draw(parts, startAngle);
  }

}

function draw(parts, startAngle) {
  var style = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < parts; i++) {
    style += border[i] + ": #FF4E4E;";
  }
  circle.setAttribute("style", style);
  totalAngle = standeredRotation + parseInt(startAngle);
  circle.style.transform = 'rotate(' + totalAngle + 'deg)';
}
```

```css
#circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="user-input">
    <label>start angle</label>
    <input type="text" id="startangle" value="0" />
    <label>end angle</label>
    <input type="text" id="endtangle" value="180" />
    <button onclick="getinput()">draw</button>
  </div>
  <div id="circle">

  </div>
</body>
```

for your last circle[2 overlap circles] angles are 0 and 270.to close circles you can position 2 divs and rotate them.